# Flutter MethodChannel in Android Service not working in release apk

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to call some static dart functions from native Android `Service` class. This is my `main` flutter class

```
// Dart code
void main() {
  initializeAndroidWidgets();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

const CHANNEL = "com.app/channel";

// Method channel for Android
void initializeAndroidWidgets() {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    // Intialize flutter
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

    const MethodChannel channel = MethodChannel(CHANNEL);

    final CallbackHandle callback = PluginUtilities.getCallbackHandle(rustMethodChannel)!;
    final handle = callback.toRawHandle();

    channel.invokeMethod('initialize', handle);
  }
}

void rustMethodChannel() async {
  // Initialize flutter
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  PreferenceRepository preferenceRepository = PreferenceRepository();
  // Create methodChannel
  const MethodChannel channel = MethodChannel(CHANNEL);
  channel.setMethodCallHandler(
            (call) async {
      final args = call.arguments;
      logDebug('on Dart ${call.method}!, args = ${args}');

      switch (call.method) {
        case 'isConnected':
          return await isConnected(preferenceRepository);
        case 'startConnect':
          var result = await startConnect(preferenceRepository);
          return result;
        case 'disconnect':
          return await disconnect();
        case 'getTestString':
          return getTestString();
        default:
          throw UnimplementedError("Unknow: ${call.method}");
      }
    },
  );
}
```

This is my service:

```
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "MyApp";
        const val CHANNEL = "com.app/channel"

        private var channel: MethodChannel? = null;
    }

    private fun initializeFlutter() {
        if (channel == null) {
            try {
                FlutterMain.startInitialization(this)
                FlutterMain.ensureInitializationComplete(this, arrayOf())

                val handle = WidgetHelper.getRawHandle(this)
                if (handle == WidgetHelper.NO_HANDLE) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't update widget because there is no handle stored!")
                    return
                }

                val callbackInfo = FlutterCallbackInformation.lookupCallbackInformation(handle)
                val entryPointFunctionName = callbackInfo.callbackName
                Log.e(
                    TAG,
                    "entryPointFunctionName = ${entryPointFunctionName}, FlutterMain.findAppBundlePath() = ${FlutterMain.findAppBundlePath()}"
                )
                // Instantiate a FlutterEngine.
                val engine = FlutterEngine(this.applicationContext)
                val entryPoint = DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint(FlutterMain.findAppBundlePath(), entryPointFunctionName)
                engine.dartExecutor.executeDartEntrypoint(entryPoint)

                GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(engine)
                channel = MethodChannel(engine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL)
            } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.e(TAG, "Starting service");
        initializeFlutter()
    }
```

When I executed the code on `debug` mode, it's working well. However, when I tried to install the release apk generated by `flutter build apk`, it showed me this error:

```
2022-11-10 15:43:54.448 10736-10736/? E/MyApp: entryPointFunctionName = rustMethodChannel, FlutterMain.findAppBundlePath() = flutter_assets
2022-11-10 15:43:54.466 10736-10736/? W/FlutterEngineCxnRegstry: Attempted to register plugin (k1.a@1df89c) but it was already registered with this FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.a@32a92a5).
2022-11-10 15:43:54.466 10736-10736/? W/FlutterEngineCxnRegstry: Attempted to register plugin (u3.a@26ce67a) but it was already registered with this FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.a@32a92a5).
2022-11-10 15:43:54.466 10736-10736/? W/FlutterEngineCxnRegstry: Attempted to register plugin (l1.a@2f37e2b) but it was already registered with this FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.a@32a92a5).
2022-11-10 15:43:54.466 10736-10736/? W/FlutterEngineCxnRegstry: Attempted to register plugin (d2.c@2600288) but it was already registered with this FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.a@32a92a5).
2022-11-10 15:43:54.466 10736-10736/? W/FlutterEngineCxnRegstry: Attempted to register plugin (g0.m@d6b421) but it was already registered with this FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.a@32a92a5).
2022-11-10 15:43:54.466 10736-10736/? W/FlutterEngineCxnRegstry: Attempted to register plugin (e2.b@8d2f046) but it was already registered with this FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.a@32a92a5).
2022-11-10 15:43:54.466 10736-10736/? W/FlutterEngineCxnRegstry: Attempted to register plugin (f2.c@329d207) but it was already registered with this FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.a@32a92a5).
2022-11-10 15:43:54.466 10736-10736/? W/FlutterEngineCxnRegstry: Attempted to register plugin (f0.t@f36bf34) but it was already registered with this FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.a@32a92a5).
2022-11-10 15:43:54.467 10736-10736/? E/MyApp: startWakeLock
2022-11-10 15:43:54.469 10736-10736/? E/MyApp: Starting service
2022-11-10 15:43:54.469 766-774/? E/statsd: Predicate 5980654721335871649 dropping data for dimension key (10)0x2010101->10327[I] (10)0x30000->com.anv3.proxy:wakelock[S] 
2022-11-10 15:43:54.477 10736-13937/? E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(668)] Could not resolve main entrypoint function.
2022-11-10 15:43:54.477 10736-13937/? E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(167)] Could not run the run main Dart entrypoint.
2022-11-10 15:43:54.479 10736-13937/? E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(385)] Could not create root isolate.
2022-11-10 15:43:54.479 10736-13937/? E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(604)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
```

Is there any reason why using `MethodChannel` inside Service is not working in `Release` mode?

Comment: i've facing the same issue. did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by add "@pragma('vm:entry-point')" to dart function

something about mycode

main.dart

```dart
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void initChatChannel(){
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setChatChannel();
}
```

[android kotlin part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycDSX.png)

refer : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123958

My English is not very good, these two issues may be related. I tried it and it worked.